# My Android phone will not boot

Tags: samsung

I have an adroid phone Samsung Trend Lite and it won't boot. It goes off immediately.

Let me explain the situation more clearly.

I got this phone from a cousin and he said that it was broken and he couldn't fix it. I got the phone and tried to power on but it shuts down in the moment it appears the words: `Samsung Trend Lite`.

I thought it was a battery moment so I plugged it and I let it for sometime. I tried to power on the phone while charging but no luck.

While charging I tried to press the power button and the home button and it showed me the battery that was charging. In beginning I thought it was a circuit fault but after that, I came to a conclusion that it wasn't.

After 1 hour passed I pressed again the Home button and the Power button in an attempt to go to the boot menu. I made it but it showed me an error. A yellow triangle with an exclamation mark.

Though I wasn't able to read the message because it disappeared too fast. I searched on google with the hopes that I could actually find something but I couldn't find anything.

If you know anything that could help me, I would be really happy. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: it is a very old device, the emmc is probably weared-out, the usb-connector may weak, or the battery is dead. there is not much hope, but if you like replace battery (or charge with external charger), you may be able to flash [CWM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2772815) or [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3111041) and play around with manual formatting partitions, flash ROMs etc from recovery mode

Answer (score 0):

Your phone bootloops. As I know, the only way to solve this problem is reflashing firmware and most likely you'll lose your data. Possible reason: modifications with root privilegies.

Comment: "message disappeared too fast" - which kind of boot loop will exit itself from bootloader?